# How to solve problems involving roots. $\sqrt{(x+3)-4\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{(x+8)-6\sqrt{x-1}} =1$

Tags: roots, quadratics

How to solve problems involving roots. If we square them they may go to fourth degree.There must be some technique to solve this.

$$\sqrt{(x+3)-4\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{(x+8)-6\sqrt{x-1}} =1$$

Comment: Please use LaTeX formatting - 5 weeks is enough time to learn!

Comment: @nbubis I'm not sure if it's $\sqrt{x}-1$ or $\sqrt{x-1}$

Comment: @egreg -  There were no brackets, so I assumed $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: its the 2nd one.

Comment: change it to whole root of x-1

Comment: @mathslover You should really learn to fix this yourself - click on the [edited](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/449300/revisions) link to see how egreg did this

Answer (score 5):

Straight, you can get the following equation :

$$
\sqrt{(2-\sqrt{x-1})^2} + \sqrt{(3-\sqrt{x-1})^2} =1
$$

which leads to the following equation :

$$
|2-\sqrt{x-1}| + |3-\sqrt{x-1}| =1
$$

Then you will have three cases to discuss :

- case : $\sqrt{x-1} \leq2$  (equivalent to $x\leq5$) :

$\sqrt{x-1} = 2$ then $x = 5$

- case : $\sqrt{x-1} >2$ and $\sqrt{x-1} <3$  (equivalent to $5<x<10$) :

The equation below can be written : 
$$
\sqrt{x-1}-2 + 3-\sqrt{x-1} =1
$$
equivalent to :
$
1=1
$

The solutions belongs to $]5,10[$

- case : $\sqrt{x-1} \geq3$  (equivalent to $x\geq10$) :

$\sqrt{x-1} = 3$ then $x = 10$

**The solutions belongs to $[5,10]$**

Comment: In what does this solution differ from mine?

Comment: @egreg, Samatix  Please, read this (and comments, answers)  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/copying-my-solution-verbatim-is-just-so-not-cool .

Comment: @vesszabo I don't think you should ping me. I'm not accusing of plagiarism, of course, but my answer appeared before this one.

Comment: @egreg, sorry I've written the answer before noticing that you added yours. Your answer was sufficient and complet

Answer (score 2):

Put $y=\sqrt{x-1}$, getting $x=y^2+1$; thus the equation becomes
$$
\sqrt{y^2-4y+4}+\sqrt{y^2-6y+9}=1
$$
which should ring a bell.

> It becomes $|y-2|+|y-3|=1$ that can be treated without resorting to squaring; divide it into cases:
>  If $y<2$, the equation becomes $2-y+3-y=1$, or $2y=4$, that means $y=2$, absurd.
>  If $2\le y\le 3$, the equation becomes $y-2+3-y=1$, an identity.
>  If $y>3$, the equation becomes $y-2+y-3=1$, or $2y=6$ and $y=3$, absurd. 
>  Therefore the solutions are all the numbers $x$ such that $2\le\sqrt{x-1}\le3$, that is $4\le x-1\le 9$ or $5\le x\le 10$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{(x+3)-4\sqrt{x-1}} + \sqrt{(x+8)-6\sqrt{x-1}} =1$$

 
Put x-1 = t^2 
so the equation becomes 
$$\sqrt{t^2+4-4t} + \sqrt{t^2+9-6t} =1$$
complete the squares . 
**EDIT:** 
My answer was incorrect. Thanks to egreg and Samatix.

Comment: Are you sure that $\sqrt{u^2}=u$?

Comment: Hey Simar, if you don't mind but $\sqrt(x^2) = |x|$ not $x$

Comment: I don't think that you reasoning is correct.

Comment: man look at x . It is in sqrt so dont we have to neglect -ve values ?

Comment: Corrected it . Sorry ! Now is it alright ?